# Position relative elements in the flow of the page after an absolute element has been placed

Tags: html, css, sass, css-position

I'm sure it is something everyone has stepped into. I got a solution but I'm looking for the best way and more solid approach to do this.

Basically what I'm trying to do is position all my relative elements in the flow of the page after an absolute element has been placed.

[image]

As soon as I `position:absolute` the red div, the remaining `position:relative` elements will flow above the absolute positioned content. The solution I found is to create an offset class like this:

```
.offset {
  position: relative;
  top: 830px;
}
```

and apply it to *every* (**damn**) element following the red div. However, I hope there is a better way to do this (I'm concerned about responsivess and overall I think is a messy solution).

```css
.absolute {
position: absolute;
top:800px;
}

.relative {
position: relative;
}

.box {
width: 1920px;
height: 1080px;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}

.blue {
background-color: blue;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.yellow {
background-color: yellow;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper relative">
  <div class="relative box red">Go over me thanks</div>
  <div class="absolute box yellow">Absolute positioned element</div>
</div>
<div class="relative box blue">Relative positioned element</div>
```

Comment: And why you put it as absolute if you wish it to still be in content flow? It makes no sense

Comment: because I need those three diamonds images to flow over the blue background you see at their back @Justinas

Comment: If you are talking about the green blocks then don't have them as children of the absolutely positioned element, then their positioning will be unaffected.

Comment: why is the red block absolutely positioned? why not relatively position it and then just minus margin top the blue div? anyway, without showing us any code we cannot help

Comment: @AndyG the green blocks are not children of the absolute positioned element, they are a detached div following the absolute positioned element in the DOM

Comment: @Pete I included a code snippet

Comment: Basically, I want that blue box to flow below the absolute positioned Yellow one, not overlap it

Comment: I see nothing yellow in your screenshot so I'm dropping out.

Comment: @AndyG the yellow box is in the snippet

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that doesn't relate to the screenshot that you started with. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `top`, but `margin-top` instead.

`top: 800px` on a relatively positioned elements will move that *one* down by 800px in relation to its original position, but the following element won't have that offset and they will overlap.

With `margin-top` the relatively positioned element will really extend down to its visible lower border.